# About some functionality on jQuery Load More for html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

When i'm searching for Load More form html I found it here on stackoverflow but is very simple and I want some functionality to edit jQuery.
the idea is showing 5 posts by click on load more but before showing i want to add loading.gif image that mean load posts.
and when no left posts on blog i want to replace "Load More" text by "No more Posts" with different class="no-more" to edit it from css because i don't want this alert, so please can someone tell me how?

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

that is demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/

Comment: Your div's are already loaded so showing next 10 will not take long and you don't need a loading image. That's for Ajax loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm succesful to add this code for change "Load More" with "No More Posts"
replace :

```
alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
```

by:

```
$(".load-more").html('<div class="no-more"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i>  No More Posts</a></div>') // if there are none left
```

And is woking fine :)
Now only i want to add loading.gif when posts is loading?

Comment: Use comments for this kind of update or update your initial post.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply do :

```
$('a').text('No More Posts')    
$('a').addClass('no-more')
```

Concerning the loading gif you only need one if you do AJAX to get the next divs. Otherwise you've already loaded all the content.

Comment: Thanks but i think that is good `$(".load-more").html('<div class="no-more"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cancel"></i>  No More Posts</a></div>') // if there are none left` and can you help me to add loading.gif image when posts load?

Comment: Are you going to use AJAX ? because if you don't do so you'll probably won't have time to see the preloader ...

Comment: ok no problem the very important for me is to change button load more by No More Posts so thank you :)